# To Find Vowel-Substring From a String

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string of lowercase English letters and an integer of the substring length. I have to find the substring of that length that contains the most vowels.

Example:

s = 'azerdii'

k = 5

The possible 5 character substrings are:

1. 'azerd' No. of vowels = 2
2. 'zerdi' No. of vowels = 2
3. 'erdii' No. of vowels = 3

So the answer should be 'erdii'

Here is my code:

```
def findSubstring(s, k):
    i = 0
    lst = []
    count = 0
    tempL = []
    
    while(i != len(s)):
        a = i+k
        temp = s[i:a]
        lst.append(temp)
        if a != len(s):
            i+=1
        else:
            break
    
    for word in lst:
        for alphabet in word:
            if alphabet in 'aeiou':
                count += 1
        tempL.append(count)
    print(lst)
    print(tempL)
    return 

s = input()

k = int(input().strip())

print(findSubstring(s, k))

I'm getting 

['azerd', 'zerdi', 'erdii']
[2, 4, 7]
```

But the count should be

```
[2, 2, 3]
```

Please forgive any stupid errors I may have. I will certainly appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you need all the substrings which contain the maximum vowels e.g. `erdii`, `irdei`, `iirde`, etc. or just anyone of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```py
def find_substr(s, k):
    substrings = [s[i:i+k] for i in range(len(s) - k + 1)] # list of substrings
    # vowels = [sum(c in 'aeiou' for c in s) for s in substrings]
    # print(vowels) # [2, 2, 3]
    return max(substrings, key=lambda s: sum(c in 'aeiou' for c in s))

print(find_substr('azerdii', 5)) # 'erdii'
```

If you un-comment the lines that are commented out, you will see the number of vowels is correctly computed as `[2, 2, 3]`.

---

Here, `sum(c in 'aeiou' for c in s)` gets the number of vowels in a string `s`, which is equivalent to

```py
count = 0
for alphabet in word:
    if alphabet in 'aeiou':
        count += 1
```

which in turn is the same as your code, *except* the line `count = 0`. After processing each `word`, you need to reset `count`. So try adding `count = 0` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset the `count=0` at line number 17.

Try this code

```
def findSubstring(s, k):
    i = 0
    lst = []
    count = 0
    tempL = []
    
    while(i != len(s)):
        a = i+k
        temp = s[i:a]
        lst.append(temp)
        if a != len(s):
            i+=1
        else:
            break
    
    for word in lst:
        count = 0
        for alphabet in word:
            if alphabet in 'aeiou':
                count += 1
        tempL.append(count)
    print(lst)
    print(tempL)
    return 

s = 'azerdii'
k = 5
print(findSubstring(s, k))
```

Comment: Thanks, @Suleman Now I know where I got wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a sliding window approach, for an optimal time complexity single-pass solution:

```
def find_substring_length_k_most_vowels(s: str, k: int) -> str:
    '''Returns first substring of length k that has the max number of vowels.'''
    vowels = set('aeiou')
    max_vowel_count = curr_vowel_count = 0
    max_window_start, max_window_end = 0, -1
    window_start = 0
    for window_end, ch in enumerate(s):
        if ch in vowels:
            curr_vowel_count += 1
        if window_end - window_start + 1 == k:
            if curr_vowel_count > max_vowel_count:
                max_vowel_count = curr_vowel_count
                max_window_start, max_window_end = window_start, window_end
            curr_vowel_count -= 1 if s[window_start] in vowels else 0
            window_start += 1
    return s[max_window_start:max_window_end + 1]


def main() -> None:
    s = 'azerdii'
    k = 5
    print(find_substring_length_k_most_vowels(s, k))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
erdii
```

Comment: This is the fastest solution. Just need to change the return statement to match the question, to:  `return s[max_window_start:max_window_end + 1] if max_vowel_count > 0 else "Not found!"`

Answer (score 0):

Brute Force Solution

Intuition :

1. Initialize a set and push all the elements of the sub string in that set(knowing that the element is a vowel). When its sizes == 5(as there are 5 vowels in English alphabet)  then increase the counter by 1
   Approach :
2. Make a function isVowel that return (1/true) when the passed character is a vowel otherwise (0/false).
3. Initialize 2 for loop
   a.  Outer loop running from 0 to word.size()(till the end of the string).
   b.  Inner loop running from i to word.size()(till the end of the string).
4. Now initialize a SET inside the outer for loop (as we don’t want that the values of previous iteration to persist in it).
5. In the inner for loop initialize a condition that  if the J th Character value is not a vowel then break the loop.
6. And if it is a vowel then insert it in the initailzed SET
7. Now again initialize a condition that if the size of SET is == 5 then increase the counter by 1.
8. At last return the counter.
   Code:

   ```
   //  Function that checks that the given character is a vowel or not

    int isVowel(char c)
   {

    if ((c == 'a') || (c == 'e') || (c == 'i') || (c == 'o') || (c == 'u'))

   {


   return 1;

   }

   return 0;

   }


   int countVowelSubstrings(string word)

   {

      int counter = 0; // initalize the counter with 0

      for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)

      {

   set<char> temp;// set initalized outside the for loop so as to avoid 
                   // the persitance of the pervious iteration values in 
                  //the set

   for (int j = i; j < word.size(); j++)

   {

       //  if the jth charcter is not a vowel then break the loop

       if (isVowel(word[j]) == 0)

       {

           break;

       }

       // else insert the char value in the SET

       temp.insert(word[j]);

       //  if size == 5 (as there are 5 vowels in English alphabet)  then 
       //  increase the counter by 1

   if (temp.size() == 5)

       {

           counter++;

       }

   }

       }

     return counter;

          }
        // Code By Ambuj Kumar
   ```

Comment: So after getting all the substrings from the original string, we are putting the substrings in `int countVowelSubstrings(string word)` to check for Vowles.
But why we are checking if the size of **temp** is equal to 5 or not.
which may or may not contain all vowels (substring).

Answer (score 0):

An almost one-liner functional approach:

```
from functools import reduce

def getVowelsLength(word, k):
    chunks = [word[i:i+k] for i in range(len(word)-(k-1))]
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x if x[1] > y[1] else y, list(zip(chunks, [sum(1 for l in w if l in 'aeiou') for w in chunks])))
```

which will give the correct answer: `('erdii', 3)`